# Pipe text from array into a new array

Tags: c

I have an array and am able to print the portion of it that I want. But what I would like to do is write that portion to a new array. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

```
  char line[128];
  char *line1;
  char *pch,*pch1;

  char key[]="REMARK 290    ";
  char key1[]="X";



  int start=24;
  int len=35;

  while (fgets(line,sizeof line, file)!=NULL)

  {
      pch=strstr(line,key);
      pch1=strstr(line,key1);


      if(pch!=NULL && pch1!=NULL){

      printf("%.*s\n",len,line+start);
```

What gets printed at the end is what I want piped into a new array.

Comment: what are you trying to print? u are passing two int's with %s. That's used for strings

Comment: I found that last line of code online but it seems to work. It prints the elements between element 24 and element 35 of my character array "line"

Comment: @Ankush  He passes one `int`, and one `char*`.  (`char* + int` yields a `char*`).  I had forgotten about that format specifier, but it takes the field width from the arguments, which is why the `len` is okay there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes are used to communicate between processes.  You can't *pipe* from one array to another.

If the `printf()` at the end of your code does what you want, then you simply want to use **[`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)** to put the result of the "print" in an array instead of sending it to `stdout`.